# vs-code terminal vs linux terminal shows different node --version

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, node.js, visual-studio-code

I upgraded node with "nvm" in kali-linux system:

```
 nvm install node
```

This installs latest node version. `nvm ls` displays this

```
default -> v14.15.1
       v15.14.0
       v16.2.0
       v16.3.0
         system
      v16.3.0
node -> stable (-> v16.3.0) (default)
stable -> 16.3 (-> v16.3.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
```

I set the default

```
  nvm alias default v16.3.0
```

I close all terminals and this sets up `v16.3.0` in terminal. However when I check on vs-code `node --version` I m still gettting "v14.15.1". I also run `nvm alias default v16.3.0` on vs-code, restart the vs-code but it still shows "v14.15.1"

Comment: Could it be related to your PATH?

Comment: Have you tried running `nvm use 16`?